# Regular expression to find all strings of a's and b's that contain an even number of a's and an even number of b's?

Tags: regex

Is it possible to count the number of times that a character has occured in a string using regular expression?
Can any regular expression be given to find the all strings  of a's and b's that contain an even number of a's and an even number of b's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple enough finite state machine: it has four states: s00, s01, s10, and s11 depending on whether you have consumed an even or odd number of `a`s and an even or odd number of `b`s.
The start state (also the end state) is the state reached by consuming an even number of both `a`s and `b`s.
The transition function looks like this:

```
d(s00, a) = s10
d(s00, b) = s01
d(s10, a) = s00
d(s10, b) = s11
d(s01, a) = s11
d(s01, b) = s00
d(s11, a) = s01
d(s11, b) = s10
```

We can eliminate state `s11`:

```
d(s00, a)  = s10
d(s00, b)  = s01
d(s10, a)  = s00
d(s10, ba) = s11
d(s10, bb) = s10
d(s01, b)  = s00
d(s01, aa) = s01
d(s01, ab) = s10
```

From this we can develop a regular expression without lookahead
by tracing all possible paths through the FSM that return once to the start state, and repeating:

```
( a (bb|ba(aa)*ab)* (a|ba(aa)*b) | b (aa|ab(bb)*ba)* (b|ab(bb)*a) )*
```

(Meaningless blanks inserted to help me keep track of nesting of parentheses.)
The idea is, if the first character is `a` you reach `s10`; then you can transition to `s10` and back to `s01` repeatedly via `(bb|ba(aa)*ab)*`, and finally return to `s00` (without repeating `s10`) either via `a` or via `ba(aa)*b`. A similar pattern (just swap the occurrences of `a` and `b`) gets you from `s00` back to `s00` via a string that starts with `b`. And you can make as many trips out and back to `s00` as you like starting with either `a` or `b`.

Comment: Thanks @David K.Simple and understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible using this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=(?:b*ab*a)*b*$)(?=(?:a*ba*b)*a*$)[ab]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gB8lZ6/2)

`(?=(?:b*ab*a)*b*$)` is a lookahead that makes sure there are even number of `a`s in the input by matching 0 or more **pairs** of `b*a` sub-pattern.

Similar check is done for even no of `b`s in `(?=(?:a*ba*b)*a*$)`

Comment: .I am not able to understand it.Can u explain it briefly?Thanks,

Comment: Check my demo as well and change test data to test this regex with combinations of `a` and `b`s. That will give you clear understanding.

Comment: .I am new to stackoverflow.I didn't knew that accepting answer removes the another accepted answer.apologies.